# "memcopy" style construction of an object in C++

Tags: c++, heap-memory, memcpy, default-constructor

In certain embedded situations, memory needs to be moved with memcopy style functions (such as from external memory, or using closed API calls).

When such a C++ object needs to be moved this way, however it doesn't have a default constructor, you can't do something like this, :

```
class Object { 
    //local data
public:
    Object(/* not a default constructor */){}
}

//elsewhere:
Object o; //compiler will complain here...
memcpy_like_function(src_address, &o, sizeof(o));
```

because `Object` doesn't have a default constructor, and thus the compiler will complain about creating Object o.

Some notes from things that have shown up in the comments:

- `memcpy_like_function` is **like** memcpy, it isn't actually memcpy.  The `src_address` isn't a pointer to an address I can reach, or an int representing a pointer to an address I can reach.  It is an int representing an address in a memory space I can't reach.  The only way for me to access this memory space is with this function.
- `Object` doesn't have a default constructor, has no virtual functions, is neither inherited from, nor inherits anything.  `Object` is [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable).

What is the correct way to deal with creating such an object in this situation, without putting it on the heap?  Preferably, I would like to get a stack allocated object that will behave correctly with scope and destructors.  For the purposes of this question, `Object` is not inheriting from anything.

Comment: Please comment before down-voting and voting to close.... it is incredibly rude to do otherwise.

Comment: @Eichhörnchen: because the memory location it is in is inaccessible outside of a closed API call...

Comment: @AndrewSpott The close-vote will include a reason - sometimes no additional comment is needed

Comment: is `src_address` just pointing to two ints, or is it actually an `Object` that was properly allocated and constructed?

Comment: @M.M: I'm sorry, I think close votes always need a comment.  Especially considering this one is "unclear what is being asked".  I can't fix it if I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @M.M src_address is an int denoting an address in another memory space.  `Object` is just an example, not meant to be necessarily representative of my situation.

Comment: You should post something that is actually representative of your situation, otherwise it is indeed unclear what you are asking.

Comment: For example, `Object o = *reinterpret_cast<Object *>(src_address);` would be a solution based on what's posted so far , but no doubt you're going to come back and say that your situation is actually different for some reason

Comment: @M.M: but `Object` does not have a copy constructor. I think that won't compile either.

Comment: See, this is the problem. In the code you've posted there is an implicitly-defined copy constructor. But you say in comments that the real code is different.  Sorry but I have to back up that close vote unless you can actually post the real code you are asking about.

Comment: I would call the code in your question bad, and borderline dangerous. A dirty hack at best. Can you really not achieve your goal in proper object-oriented C++, with no memcpy_like_functions?

Comment: @M.M. I think you haven't understood my comments, or you are not reading the question carefully enough.  I mentioned that `src_address` is not necessarily a pointer, which makes `reinterpret_cast` useless.  I never mentioned anything about a lack of an implicitly defined copy constructor, just a lack of a default constructor.

Comment: @AndrewSpott my suggested code works if `src_address` is an int containing a memory address.

Comment: @M.M: it was me who said that, not the OP. I may be wrong or misunderstanding something.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Ah. Apologies to Andrew Spott in that respect. Every class has a copy-constructor . (in some cases it is implicitly `delete`d or private, but nothing in this question suggests that)

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: No, I can't.  Do you have any experience with embedded systems?  I'm trying to access a memory space that is segmented from the normal memory space.  All I have to access such a space is a function that behaves like memcopy

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: I would really like to be able to do this with C++ idioms... but all that is available to me is C style functions.  The whole reason for this is to try and keep the API as C++ like as possible

Comment: @M.M:  src_address is an int representing an address in another memory address space... not in the space I have access to.

Comment: @M.M: sorry, I corrected the above comment

Comment: You could use your copy function to copy the data to a buffer in the "normal" space, and then construct `o` normally

Comment: Question and comments are very unclear. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @M.M:  If you want to clarify what you mean, by "construct `o` normally", I would appreciate it.

Comment: `Object o(a, b);`, where you got `a` and `b` values set up by using your memcopy function

Comment: @M.M This implies the constructor exists to create the object from the values stored... this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Objects can only be constructed using their constructor (or aggregate initialization, for aggregates)

Comment: Based on these comments it sounds like you need to make some modifications to `Object` to support creation via the memcpy-like function (along the lines of "evan"'s answer)

Comment: How does the object get to be in the external/unaccessible memory to start with? Also, are you able to change/enhance the class Object you are working with?

Comment: @harmic through a similar memcpy like function.  At the moment I'm trying to avoid changing the Object class, though it is looking like that isn't possible.

Comment: @AndrewSpott: I see. I have embedded experience, but not with Harvard architecture. Fair enough.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: this actually isn't a Harvard architecture system. It is a [esp8266](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266).  The RTC has its own memory and offers APIs to access said memory, which is what brought up the question.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a horribly bad idea, but assuming that your `memcpy_like_function` actually works, then you can just add a constructor to `Object`

```
class Object { 
    //local data
public:
    Object(void* src_address)
    {
        memcpy_like_function(src_address, this, sizeof(*this));
    }
};

//elsewhere:
Object o(src_address);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot safely copy an object using a `memcpy`-like function unless the object is a POD type. If the object is a POD type, you should be able to use:

```
char destination[sizeof(Object)];
memcpy_like_function(src_address, destination, sizeof(destination));
Object* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(destination);
```

My gut-feel says that that should work under all compilers for POD types. Whether it is cause for undefined behavior under some rules of the standard, I am not sure.

If that is cause for undefined behavior under some rules of the standard, you won't be able to save a POD-type to a binary file and read it from the binary file in a standards compliant manner. They rely on the bit-pattern written to a file and read from a file to represent the object.

The following program produces the expected result under g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct Object
{
   int i;
   double d;
   Object(int ii, double dd) : i(ii), d(dd) {}
};

int main()
{
   Object o1(10, 20.34);
   char dest[sizeof(Object)];
   memcpy(dest, &o1, sizeof(dest));
   Object* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(dest);
   std::cout << o1.i << ", " << o1.d << std::endl;
   std::cout << ptr->i << ", " << ptr->d << std::endl;
}
```

**Update, in response to OP's comments**

The following program works as expected under g++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

struct Object
{
   int i;
   double d;
   Object(int ii, double dd) : i(ii), d(dd) {}
};

Object testFunction(Object o1)
{
   char dest[sizeof(Object)];
   memcpy(dest, &o1, sizeof(dest));
   Object* ptr = reinterpret_cast<Object*>(dest);
   return *ptr;
}

int main()
{
   Object o1(10, 20.34);
   Object o2 = testFunction(o1);
   std::cout << o1.i << ", " << o1.d << std::endl;
   std::cout << o2.i << ", " << o2.d << std::endl;
   o2.i = 25;
   o2.d = 39.65;
   std::cout << o2.i << ", " << o2.d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: note that it would not be permitted to use an `Object` lvalue to access the destination subsequently

Comment: That isn't the same thing.  That gets me a stack array with the same data, but not a stack object.

Comment: This is still an object that I can't return from a function... though the edit to the question to make that clear will have to wait.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, you sure can. Just use `return *ptr;`.

Comment: No, because destination will disappear when the function returns.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, That does not matter. You will return the contents of the array as a whole just as though it were an instance of `Object`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that destination will be freed when the function returns and the pointer is pointing at nothing.

Comment: Sorry:  this will work some of the time but is undefined behavior.  The memory hasn't been overwritten in your example, but is no longer protected.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, your fears are unfounded. Like I said, if that is cause for undefined behavior, we won't be able to write to binary files and read from those binary files in a standards compliant manner.

Comment: @AndrewSpott notice that @R_Sahu is returning `*ptr`, which means he is returning the object by value, not by pointer. `o2` is a copy of the object that was originally memcpy'd into the local array dest.

Answer (score 2):

> because `Object` doesn't have a default constructor

When `Object` doesn't have a default constructor,

```
//Object o;//NG
```

there is no way to construct `Object` unless call another ctor or factory function. Because of that, you cannot call memcpy-like function.

When you have way to construct `Object`, to use memcpy-like function, `Object` class **must** grantee that it is `trivially copyable class` and `standard-layout class`(not equal to `POD class`).

`trivial class` : `trivially copyable class` && has no default user-defined constructor
`POD class` : `trivial class` && `standard-layout class`

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is simply use an array of bytes, then cast.

Note: what you are doing is not really good C++ practice, typically you should use assignment operators or copy constructors, and you should stick to the safer C++ casts rather than a brute-force C-style cast.

Anyway, that being said, this code will work:

```
class Object {
    int i;

public:
    Object(int i) : i(i) {}

    void foo() const {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void bla() {
    Object one(1);
    char *bytes = new char[sizeof(Object)];
    memcpy(bytes, &one, sizeof(Object));
    Object &anotherOne = (Object &) *bytes;
    anotherOne.foo();
    const Object &oneMore = (Object) *bytes;
    oneMore.foo();
    Object *oneMoreTime = (Object *) bytes;
    oneMoreTime->foo();
    delete[] bytes;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
1
1
```

In summary, you need to allocate a region of memory on the stack or the heap that will become the Object instance.

Comment: Note: this is undefined behaviour.  (May or may not appear to work on any particular implementation)

Comment: `(Object) *bytes` uses the first `char`'s value to invoke the constructor of `Object`, this is probably not what was intended

Comment: Not quite: C dictates that structs are allocated contiguously in memory, and so in C++ if the data fields are POD, as in this case, then this will work.  However, in cases where the objects are not POD, you're right, this might not work.

Comment: No , accessing `bytes`' content as `Object` violates the strict aliasing rule, regardless of POD-ness.  The latter would be relevant if you constructed an `Object` and then memcpy'd content into the `Object`.

Comment: This also ignores the "without putting it on the heap" requirement. Along with directly accessing the memory, not doing it through the memcpy like function.

Comment: @Andrew Spott, I forgot that "heap" comment at the end of the question, but this code works the same off the heap, just use `char bytes[sizeof(Object)] `instead of `char *bytes = new char[sizeof(Object)]`

Comment: Then you can't return the object... bytes gets freed.

Comment: @Andrew Spott Not if it is a global or static.  And additionally, there was no part of the question saying that it cannot be stack-allocated because it must be returned.  Stack-allocated objects can never be returned.

Comment: Stack allocated objects can be returned through the copy constructor. And they act like C++ objects (destroyed when out of scope etc) which is what I would like.  I'll try to update the question when I get a chance

Comment: @Andrew Spott If you use the copy constructor, then the returned object is not the same object, it's a copy.  But yeah, you can do that if you want.  Seems strange you would use a copy constructor in a question designed to explicitly avoid using copy constructors or assignment operators.

Comment: @SeanF: Is the question unclear?  Their is a specific reason I can't use assignment operators or copy constructors, and that reason only applies to getting the data from some other memory location,  once the memcopy is done, those are all fair game.